Need to perform AWS calls for account ***, but no credentials have been configured GITHUB ACTIONS
I am running a very simple github action script (see below). It has always worked perfectly well (it worked yesterday) but now all of a sudden it fails with:
  This API will be removed in the next major release.
Warning:  aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions.StateMachineProps#definition is deprecated.
  use definitionBody: DefinitionBody.fromChainable()
  This API will be removed in the next major release.
 ⏳  Bootstrapping environment aws://***/us-east-1...
 ❌  Environment aws://***/us-east-1 failed bootstrapping: Error: Need to perform AWS calls for account ***, but no credentials have been configured
    at SdkProvider.forEnvironment (/home/runner/work/tester/tester/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:593:5639101)
    at async _BootstrapStack.lookup (/home/runner/work/tester/tester/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:592:8579)
    at async Bootstrapper.modernBootstrap (/home/runner/work/tester/tester/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:593:1084)
    at async /home/runner/work/tester/tester/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:650:1671
Need to perform AWS calls for account ***, but no credentials have been configured
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Here is the yml being run:
name: CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3 # Updated to the latest version

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3 # Updated to the latest version
        with:
          node-version: "20"

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          npm install -g yarn
          yarn

      - name: Deploy to AWS (prod)
        run: |
          cd infrastructure
          yarn
          npx cdk bootstrap --all -c env=prod aws://$PROD_ACCOUNT_ID/us-east-1
          npx cdk deploy -c env=prod --require-approval never --all
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: us-east-1
          PROD_ACCOUNT_ID: ${{ secrets.PROD_ACCOUNT_ID }}

I checked my github secrets and they look fine, they weren't changed in the last 4 months, I also checked my aws credentials, they are still active and working. No changes there either.

We were seeing something very similar on Azure DevOps. We found an issue on GitHub which covers it and saw that the latest version of the aws-cdk NPM package has been deprecated.
Our builds started succeeding again with the previous version.

Thank you Scott Munro for your insight. I added the following to my script and now it works:
- name: Install stable version of AWS CDK
        run: npm install -g aws-cdk@2.166.0 # Use a stable previous version

